# Clone object with random rotation and position

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I have one white line, behind a mask that is in the shape of my logo. And behind that a black background.
I want this line to duplicate once every 5 frames in a completely new 'position' and 'rotation' under the mask, until the whole thing becomes white with lines. I am a complete beginner to expressions and I don't even know exactly where to put the code. I think this is kind of what I am looking for:

```
seedRandom(1, true);
x=random(minvalue, maxvalue);
y=random(minvalue, maxvalue);
z=random(minvalue, maxvalue);
[x,y,z]
```

But this doesn't clone the line.

Any help would be great

Max

Comment: n will eventually equal infinity?! what have you tried so far? Could you please post some sample code so we can take a look?

Comment: n -> ∞ sorry. Have you had a look at the video? Yeah hold on.

Comment: I have just been copy and pasting stuff from [here](http://www.motionscript.com/mastering-expressions/random-1.html) but no success :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot clone an object with an After Effects expression.  I think you will probably want to add the random position/rotation expression to one layer, then duplicate that layer (command+d on Mac) many times, and then use an After Effects script like this one:

http://aescripts.com/pt_shiftlayers/

(Copy it to `Adobe After Effects CS#/Scripts/ScriptUI Panels/`, restart AE, and then open it from Window > Scripts > pt_shiftlayers.jsx or something like that).

It will offset your layers the number of frames you specify, 5 in your case.  (The script is pay-what-you-want, so you can set the price to $0 and give it a try for free, or pay for it if you really appreciate the developer's work.)

If that doesn't suit your needs, you may be able to use a particle system plugin like Trapcode Particular or CC Particle World to generate a particle every 5 frames with no movement, random rotation, random position.

Let me know if this works for you.